# Functions are slow when querying Azure Hyperscale secondary replica

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I have a ASP .NET Core application using EF and an Azure SQL database.  We recently migrated the database to the Hyperscale service tier.  The database has 2 vCores and 2 secondary replicas.  When we have a function query a secondary replica (by either modifying the connection string to include ApplicationIntent=READONLY; or by using a new services.AddDbContext() from our Startup.cs) we find that functions take 20-30x longer to execute.

For instance, this function:

```
public async Task<List<StaffWorkMuchModel>> ExemptStaffWorkMuchPerWeek(int quarterId, int facilityId) {
            using (var dbConnection = (IDbConnection) _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IDbConnection))) {
                dbConnection.ConnectionString += "ApplicationIntent=READONLY;";
                dbConnection.Open();
                return (await dbConnection.QueryAsync<StaffWorkMuchModel>("ExemptStaffWorkMuchPerWeek", new {
                    id_qtr = quarterId,
                    id_fac = facilityId
                }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 150)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

We have tried to query the secondary replica directly using SQL Server Management Studio and have found that the queries all return in less than a second.  Also, when we add breakpoints in our code, it seems like the queries are returning results immediately.  Most of the pages we are having issues with use ajax to call 4+ functions very similar to the one above.  It almost seems like they are not running asynchronously.

This same code runs great when we comment out:

```
dbConnection.ConnectionString += "ApplicationIntent=READONLY;";
```

Any idea what could be causing all of our secondary replica functionss to load so slow?

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a resolution to this?

Comment: No, we gave up on this and moved all queries back to the primary database.